# Finding xy coordinates of shelves in a store floorplan in r

Tags: r, image, coordinates

I'm working on the following: I have a store layout, example see below (cannot add the real thing for GDPR reasons but the example should do the trick) on which I have xy coordinates from visitors (anonymous of course)

[image: Store layout]

I already placed a grid on the picture so I can see which route they take in the store. That works fine. origin is bottom left and x & y are scaled from 0-100.
So far so good. Now next step is identifying the coordinates of the shelves, rectangles in the picture. Is there a way to do this without having to do this manually? The real store layout contains more than 900 shelves or am I pushing out the boat too far?

The output I'm looking for is a dataframe that contains a shelve ID and the coordinates for the corners. Idea is to create some heatmaps in the store to see that there are blind spots, hotspots, ...

The second analysis needs also the integer points. The idea is to create vectors of visitor points so we get a direction to which they are looking. By using the scope of what a human being can see I would give percentages of "seen" the products based on intersection with integer points.

thx!
JL

Comment: Can you show an example of (some of) the output you might expect for this input? Do you want coordinates for the corners of the shelves? Integer points along the lines? Something else?

Comment: roughly you could use the R package pixmap to map the values of each pixel at  all coordinates then assuming no lines intersect create matrices for each closed rectangle

Comment: @ Gregor, I edited the question. Forgot to do that in my hastiness.

Comment: If such a detailed plan exists, it must be available in electronic form somewhere (CAD?) in a format from which you could export object coordinates...

Comment: I would try density based clustering. If the shelves are axis-parallel then it is easy to extract the rectangle coordinates from the clusters.

Comment: Did the clustering approach I outlined in my answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to perform clustering on the black pixels of the image. The clusters are then the shelves. If the shelves are axis parallel you can find the rectangles by just taking min/max in each direction. This works quite well:

[image: The found rectangles]

Sample code (I converted the image to PNG as it is easier to read than gif):

```
library(png)
library(dbscan)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)


img <- readPNG("G18JU.png")



is_black <-
  img %>% 
  apply(c(1, 2), sum) %>%  #sum all color channels
  {. < 2.5} %>% # we assume black if the sum is lower than 2.5 (max value is 3)
  which(arr.ind=TRUE) # the indices of the black pixels



clust <- dbscan(is_black, 2) # identify clusters

rects <- 
  as.tibble(is_black) %>% 
  mutate(cluster = clust$cluster) %>% # add cluster information
  group_by(cluster) %>% 
  ## find corner points of rectangles normalized to [0, 1]
  summarise(xleft = max(col) / dim(img)[2],
            ybottom = 1 - min(row) / dim(img)[1],
            xright = min(col) / dim(img)[2],
            ytop = 1 - max(row) / dim(img)[1])

## plot the image and the rectangles
plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 1), type="n")
rasterImage(img, 0, 0, 1, 1)
for (i in seq_len(nrow(rects))) {
  rect(rects$xleft[i], rects$ybottom[i], rects$xright[i], rects$ytop[i],
       border = brewer.pal(nrow(rects), "Paired")[i], lwd = 2)
}
```

Of course this approach also detects other black lines as "rectangles" (e.g. the black border). But I guess you can easily create a "clean" image.

Edit: extend method to find shelves that share a black line

To extend the method such that it can separate shelves that share a black line:

First, identify the rectangles in the way outlined above.
Then, extract each rectangle from the image and compute the row means. This gives you a 1d image (= line) for each rectangle. In this line apply thresholding and clustering as before. The clusters are now the black line segments, and the mean of each cluster corresponds to a vertical line shared by two shelves.
To find horizontal shared lines, the same procedure can be applied, but with column means instead of row means.

Comment: Hi AEF, Your code works nicely. I learned something new!. Thank you for it. The one thing that it does not do is identify 2 shelves (I didn't think of that one in advance) that are back to back and therefore share a same black line.

Comment: To separate such shelves with shared lines, I think you can apply the same procedure recursively, as described in my edit above.

Comment: great. Thank for the inspiration. Made a clean plan and works like a charm!. Much appreciated